# How to enforce type signature

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

In the code below, `queue_it` alters the type signature in an unexpected way. How do I resolve this?

```
module foo = 
    type MBase() =
        member __.id = 42

    type User() = inherit MBase()
    type User2() = inherit MBase()

    let queue_it f  = fun x -> f x 
    let _find(x:int) = (Unchecked.defaultof<#MBase>)

    let find0 = fun x -> _find x    // int -> #MBase
    let findq0 = queue_it _find     // int -> MBase  ??

    let u1 : User  = find0 42
    let u2 : User2 = find0 42
    let u3 : User  = findq0 42
    let u4 : User2 = findq0 42 // error: Expected User2 but given User
```

Comment: In what situations is `queue_it` useful? In F#, anytime you see `fun x -> f x`, that expression can be replaced by `f`. So the definition of `queue_it` reduces to `let queue_it f = f`. Perhaps this is a simplification of your real code, but in this case it's simplified so much that I don't understand why you would want to use `queue_it` at all, since it's equivalent to (and could be replaced by) the built-in `id` function.

Comment: Yes, it is a huge simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to resolve is the easy part, make `findq0` a **generic function**:

```
let findq0 x = queue_it _find x // int -> 'a
```

The difference with what you had is that in your version

```
let findq0 = queue_it _find    // int -> User
```

`findq0` is a **generic value**, that is a problem for .Net that usually results in an error message like this

> Value restriction. The value 'findq0' has been inferred to have
>   generic type
>       val findq0 : (int -> '_a) when '_a :> Answer.foo.MBase     Either make the arguments to 'findq0' explicit or, if you do not intend for
>   it to be generic, add a type annotation.

You can see the message if you comment out the last 2 lines of your code. F# tries to avoid that message by guessing a non-generic value based on your first usage of the `findq0` which is:

```
    let u3 : User  = findq0 42
```

This line tells F# that `findq0` should return a value of type `User` and so it determines that it should be of type `int -> User`. The next line contradicts it and so you get an error saying:

> This expression was expected to have type
>       'User2'     but here has type
>       'User'

Comment: Son-of-a-Beaver!  Simple, but I don't think I would have ever thought of that.  THANK YOU!!  Any idea why the error is happening in the first place or why your solution fixes it?

Comment: Yes, check my longer answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.